# XSLT replace string with array of text and nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

Let's say I have the following XML input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <urls>
    <url>http://foo</url>
    <url>http://bar</url>
  </urls>
  <resources lang="en-US">
    <resourceString id='url-fmt'>See URL: {0}</resourceString>
  </resources>
</root>
```

I would like to produce the following output with XSL (can use 1.0, 2.0 or even 3.0):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
  <p>See URL: <a href="http://foo">http://foo</a></p>
  <p>See URL: <a href="http://bar">http://bar</a></p>
</body>
```

I have the following XSL stylesheet stub, but I struggle to find the appropriate function which will tokenize the resource string, extract {0} and replace it with a node. `replace()` seems to be of no help since it operates only with strings:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:variable name="urlResString"
                select="/root/resources/resourceString[@id='url-fmt']" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/urls/url" />
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="url">
    <p>
      <xsl:variable name='linkToInsert'>
        <a href='{.}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of
           select="replace($urlResString, '\{0}', $linkToInsert)" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is generated here is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
  <p>See URL: http://foo</p>
  <p>See URL: http://bar</p>
</body>
```

If you can guide me to the correct functions to use, that would be great.

Note: I may have to do this on strings with both `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. a bit like the format-string functions in .NET.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `xsl:analyze-string` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="urlResString"
        select="/root/resources/resourceString[@id='url-fmt']" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/urls/url" />
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="url">
        <p>
            <xsl:variable name='linkToInsert'>
                <a href='{.}'><xsl:value-of select='.'/></a>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$urlResString" regex="\{{\d\}}">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$linkToInsert"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:copy/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <xsl:template match="root/urls">
        <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="url">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select=" substring-before(parent::urls/following-sibling::resources/resourceString,' {')"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>
            </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="resources"/>
Try it
```

Comment: thank you, that would do it in this case, but the solution from Joel is more elegant and will fit better with other localizations, where the `{0}` string can be in the middle of the string, and can be extended to support multiple placeholders in the string more easily